# Can I parse a date to fit a String Array?

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, date, split

Im having a String array in my constructor which is supposed to read a line in a .txt document by using a bufferedreader. It is containing Strings int´s and two dates. My structure looks like this:

```
Private String Name;
Private int Number;
Private Date BDate;

String[] splitsarray = line.split("%");     
this.Name= splitsarray [0];  
this.Number= Integer.parseInt(splitsarray [1]);
```

I wan't to do someting like `this.BDate= splitsarray [2]` but i can't figuer out how to make it work.

Any hints or tips for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the right date pattern in the [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) constructor argument.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
this.BDate = formatter.parse(splitsarray [2]);
```

Comment: Thank you it worked almost as i wanted it. But why does the format include time and why does it transform `100911` in to `Sat Oct 09 00:00:00 CEST 2010` ?

Comment: @Handsken: you did not pass the time.therefore the time value is pointing to 00:00:00

Comment: @Handsken: don't care about the rest of the thing which is just a textual representation. you don't need to care about the time part

Comment: okej i understand, but what if I don't want to print out the time, can i exclude it?

Comment: @Handsken: Use the same formatter like this:`System.out.println(formatter.format(BDate));`

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the JDK text format classes:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Or alternatively, look at using something like Joda Time, which is an external dependency, but has a rich API.

An example:

```
String date = "2011-11-05T09:00:00";
java.text.SimpleDateFormat fmt = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
java.util.Date d = fmt.parse(date);
System.out.println(d);
//Sat Nov 05 09:00:00 GMT 2011
```